# Use javascript to remove tags without ids

Tags: javascript, parent, html

I'm new to javascript but I believe it can give me the desired results I'm trying to achieve.

I am being provided with an ordered list that is displaying as:

```
<div class ="level-section" style="">
<td><a>
<td><a>
<td><a>
</div>

<div class ="level-section">
<td>Apple<a>
<td>Bread<a>
<td>Cookie<a>
</div>
```

Is there a way to remove every occurrence of `"<div class ="level-section" style="">"` and leave the divider tags that do not have `'style=""'`? If I remove the divider tags by the class name it will remove the other items that actually have content. This is obviously a crappy way of doing it, but I'm not in a position to argue a different/better solution. I googled and keep seeing a reference to parentnode.remove and parentnode.removechild but I am beyond lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.level-section[style]');
var l = divs.length;

for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    divs[i].parentNode.removeChild( divs[i] );
}
```

This'll remove all `class="level-section"` elements, and all of its children.

---

**P.S.** Your posted HTML is invalid.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I updated the html. This would normally work but the data that is being provided to me has <div class ="level-section" style=""> and <div class ="level-section" style=""> The only difference between the two are the style="" I want to remove only the dividers that have style=""

Comment: @snapplex - Use the `.level-section[style]` selector. I updated the answer.

Comment: I'm receiving this error "Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelectorAll'

Comment: @snapplex - What browser (and what version) are you using? If it's IE8, [make sure your page is not in Quirks/Compatibillity mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920365/ie8-does-not-support-queryselectorall).

Comment: I'm using IE9 and I removed compatibility mode and refreshed the page to receive this error  "Unable to get value of the property 'removeChild': object is null or undefined

Comment: @snapplex - That was a typo in my code. It should be `parentNode`, not `parentnode`. I fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the tags with class="className":

```
$('.className').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var divs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('level-selection'),0);
for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++){
    if(divs[i].hasAttribute('style')){
       divs[i].parentNode.removeChild(divs[i]);
    }
}
```