# Highlight empty select box after alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, alert

I have a site using input:text, select and select multiple elements that generate a text output on button click.

Having searched SO, I found examples of validation code that will alert the user when a select field returns an empty value-

```
// alert if a select box selection is not made
    var selectEls = document.querySelectorAll('select'),
        numSelects = selectEls.length;

    for(var x=0;x<numSelects;x++) {
        if (selectEls[x].value === '') {
            alert('One or more required fields does not have a choice selected... please check your form');
            return false;
            $(this).addClass("highlight");

        }
```

At the end, I tried to add a condition after the alert is dismissed, such that the offending select box will be highlighted by adding the 'highlight' class - but this doesn't do anything. My .highlight css is `{border: 1px red solid;}`

Any help here?

**UPDATED WITH ANSWER - Thanks @Adam Rackis**

This code works perfectly. I added a line to remove any added '.highlight' class for selects that did not cause an error after fixing

```
// alert if a select box selection is not made
    var selectEls = document.querySelectorAll('select'),
    numSelects = selectEls.length;
    $('select').removeClass("highlight");//added this to clear formatting when fixed after alert
    var anyInvalid = false;
    for(var x=0;x<numSelects;x++) {
        if (selectEls[x].value === '') {
            $(selectEls[x]).addClass("highlight");
            anyInvalid = true;
        }}
        if (anyInvalid) {
            alert('One or more required fields does not have a choice selected... please check your form');
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: You are returning before addClass. Place `return false;` after `$(this).addClass("highlight");` and btw what does `this` means here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  In your loop, `this` does not refer to each select that you're checking.

Also, you're returning false prior to the highlight class being added.  You'll probably want to keep track of whether any select's are invalid, and return false at the **very end** after you're done with all validation.

Finally, consider moving your alert to the very bottom, so your user won't see multiple alerts.

```
var anyInvalid = false;
for(var x=0;x<numSelects;x++) {
    if (selectEls[x].value === '') {
        $(selectEls[x]).addClass("highlight");
        anyInvalid = true;
    }
}
if (anyInvalid) {
    alert('One or more required fields does not have a choice selected... please check your form');
    return false;
}
```

---

Also, since you're already using jQuery, why not take advantage of its features a bit more:

```
$('select').each(function(i, sel){
    if (sel.value === '') {
        $(el).addClass("highlight");
        anyInvalid = true;
    }
});
if (anyInvalid) {
    alert('One or more required fields does not have a choice selected... please check your form');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that nearly works for me: I used the top suggestion, but I think there is a missing closing '}' for the 'for' expression. I added it to the end of the code. Also, I get the offending selectbox highlighted, but without an alertbox first? Any ideas why?

Comment: @user1837608 - that's right - the alert should show last.  It should first highlight ALL bad selects, and then show *one* alert.  Before you were just highlighting the first bad select and then returning.  I would recommend you do all validation before failing out so your user can see all errors up front.

Comment: Got it. Your code worked just fine - I didn't realize that I turned off all alerts after an earlier code attempt showed multiple alerts.

Comment: I noticed I get a javascript 'object does not support this propert or method' error when i try the code in IE8? Yet, queryselectorALL is supposedly supported in IE8? Do you have any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: @user1837608 - take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920365/ie8-does-not-support-queryselectorall