# IE Error : Unable to set value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I can't use JQuery for this, yet I can't find a way to fix my code for IE8. It works well in all other browsers (and works for IE9+).

This is a banner rotator and it stops working at the line to hide the banner that's visible.

```
var bannerRotation = setInterval(function () {
    var img = document.querySelectorAll('#contentBannerRotator img');
    var banner = document.querySelectorAll('#contentBannerRotator a[style="display: block;"]');
    if (!banner || banner.length < 1) 
        var banner = document.querySelectorAll('#contentBannerRotator a[style="display:block;"]');

    banner[0].style.display = "none"; /* This is where the error occurs */

    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * img.length);
    img[rand].parentNode.style.display = "block";
}, 30000);
```

It seems like IE8 can't find a match to the query selector.

You can see the [error live here](http://www.cablevision.qc.ca/fr/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=193&Itemid=226).

**EDIT:** The document is not going in Quirks mode, so the `querySelectorAll` method is supposed to work fine.

Comment: If I remember correctly QSA is not supported by IE8

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920365/ie8-does-not-support-queryselectorall

Comment: @RUJordan Thank you. I checked and my document is not going in Quirks mode. the `X-UA-Compatible` meta line does not help either. As stated in the answer link you provided, QSA is supposed to be functionnal in a standard declared doctype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Error explanation

`querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are not fully supported by IE8, hence its irregular responses to my queries.

---

### Solution

I created an independant loop for IE8. The loop is only executed if nothing is found within the `banner[0]` element/objet or it is undefined.
IE8 has a specific array structure for child nodes, with the `all` array.

***JavaScript***

```
var bannerRotation = setInterval(function () {
    var img = document.querySelectorAll('#contentBannerRotator img');
    var bannerContainer = document.querySelector('#contentBannerRotator');
    var banner = document.querySelectorAll('#contentBannerRotator a[style="display: block;"]');


    if (!banner[0] || banner.length < 1) {
        /* Fix for IE8 */
        for (var i = 0; i < bannerContainer.childNodes[0].all.length; i++) {
            if (bannerContainer.childNodes[0].all[i].nodeName == "A") {

                if (bannerContainer.childNodes[0].all[i].style.display == "block") {
                    bannerContainer.childNodes[0].all[i].style.display = "none";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        banner[0].style.display = "none";
    }

    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * img.length);
    img[rand].parentNode.style.display = "block";
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to detect if element exists:

```
if(typeof banner[0] != 'undefined') {
    banner[0].style.display = "none"; /* This is where the error occurs */
}
```

update:

also read please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920365/ie8-does-not-support-queryselectorall)

Comment: Yes, this fixes the error message, but it won't hide the visible banner, making the next banner show on top of the already visible one and fill the whole page with banners. Thanks for your help anyways, it's appreciated.

Comment: @JeffNoel I suggest you, if it's possible, to use jQuery or some different javascript framework, which eliminates browsers incompatibilities.

Comment: I would be done with this issue if using a framework/library would be permitted by my director, trust me!

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` body does basically nothing, is that a typo?

```
var banner = document.querySelectorAll('#contentBannerRotator a[style="display: block;"]');
    if (!banner || banner.length < 1) 
        var banner = document.querySelectorAll('#contentBannerRotator a[style="display:block;"]');
        //  the exact same selector again?      ^
```

You're using the same selector, while it seems you want to fallback to another element guaranteed to exist. So fix the selector and you fix that error.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment, not an answer?

Comment: The `if` is there since the fallback query contains a space. I thought since IE8 doesn't pick up the element at first it could be because of the query itself and its syntax.

Comment: @JeffNoel I hadn't notice that, sorry. But it could be the attribute selector is not supported in ie8. QSA is supported according to mdn and caniuse, but support is limited.

Comment: @bfavaretto The regular querySelector does not seem to work either. Thank you for your time, I'll build a quick loop and see if it works checking each element'a property everytime. That might be my last resort solution.