# Why this function not work on IE 7 , 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

How to apply for work on IE7 , 8

for test, fill 1 into input and then press button , input will change border to red and return false.

But ie7 8 not work all.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
<div>
    <p>
        <label>            
            <input type="text" class="price" size="20" name="price[]">
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" class="price" size="20" name="price[]">
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" class="price" size="20" name="price[]">
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkform ( form )
{  
  var list = document.querySelectorAll(".price");
  var z;
  var input;
  var isValid = true;
  var value;

  // Loop through the list
  for (z = 0; z < list.length; ++z) {
    console.log("z = " + z);
    // Get this input
    input = list[z];

    // Check its value
    if (input.value != "" && parseInt(input.value, 10) < 1.5) {
      input.style.border = "1px solid red";
      isValid = false;
    }
    else {
      input.style.border = "1px solid #d5d5c5";
    }
  }

  // Return result
  return isValid;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting errors ? What does the debugger say ?

Comment: no any error, just ie7 ,8

Comment: Why do you load jQuery if you don't use it? (as that would probably fix your error…)

Comment: querySelector would work in ie8 and further..

Comment: @ Tim Medora - can i change `querySelectorAll` to other for good ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 does not support querySelectorAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920365/ie8-does-not-support-queryselectorall)

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, you can use `$(".price")`, which will call `querySelectorAll()` where appropriate and fallback to handle older browsers.

Comment: @ nietonfir - could you please tell me where ?

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` is an HTML5 DOM API, IE7, 8 are not ready for it.

See [**this page**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) for more info.

Alternatively, since you are using jquery, you can use `$(".price")` instead.

Comment: You're right, anonymous down voting without an explanation is in my opinion a yellow act. They can down vote that ;-)

Comment: can somebody explain to me why this answer got so many down vote ?

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with this answer down vote needs an explanation. Anonymous down vote cannot be accepted.

Comment: @LeoDeng You added this line : Alternatively, since you are using jquery, you can use $(".price") instead. So got upvote else there was no answer relevant for the OP....