# "JScript object expected" in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to get all Elements of a HTML page, having a specific id. This works fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

```js
    var value_fields_value = [];
    var value_fields_alert = [];
    var Variables = [];
    var e;

    
    value_fields_value = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id^=value_]'));
    for(var i in value_fields_value){
        Variables.push(new Element(value_fields_value[i], new Adresse(value_fields_value[i].id.toString().replace('value_', ''), null, null, null, null)));
    }
```

This should work in Internet Explorer too, but I'm getting the Error message "JScript object expected".

Does anyone have a idea what to do? (without using jquery)

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE8 does not support querySelectorAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920365/ie8-does-not-support-queryselectorall)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to be backwards compatible with IE8, you can't use `querySelectorAll`. You'll want to use `getElementsByTagName` or select them individually.

Also, the `for/in` loop is designed to loop over all the properties in an object, you have an array that you want to loop through. The code should be like this:

```js
var value_fields_alert = [];
var Variables = [];
var e;

// No need to pre-declare this to an empty array when you are just going
// to initialize it to an array anyway
var value_fields_value = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id^=value_]'));

// You can loop through an array in many ways, but the most traditional and backwards compatible
// is a simply for counting loop:
for(var i = 0; i < value_fields_value.length; ++i){
  Variables.push(new Element(value_fields_value[i], new Adresse(value_fields_value[i].id.toString().replace('value_', ''), null, null, null, null)));
}

// Or, you can use the more modern approach:

// The Array.prototype.forEach() method is for looping through array elements
// It takes a function as an argument and that function will be executed for
// each element in the array. That function will automatically be passed 3 arguments
// that represent the element being iterated, the index of the element and the array itself
value_fields_value.forEach(function(el, in, ar){
  Variables.push(new Element(el, new Adresse(el.id.toString().replace('value_', ''), null, null, null, null)));
});
```