# Issue with filter and queryselectorall in IE8

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where i should get the active elements in a page and perform operation based on the elements. The method should work in both ie8 & ie11. Below is the code which is working for IE11 but not for IE8. I knew that filter or queryselectorall used in the below code is causing the problem. Could someone help me on this.

```
    function focusNextElement(keyCode) {
        var focussableElements = 'select:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]),input[type=radio]:not([disabled]),input[type=text]:not([disabled]), [tabindex]:not([disabled]):not([tabindex="-1"])';
        if (document.activeElement && document.activeElement.form) {

            var focussable = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.activeElement.form.querySelectorAll(focussableElements),
    function (element) {
        return element.offsetWidth > 0 || element.offsetHeight > 0 || element === document.activeElement 
    });
            var index = focussable.indexOf(document.activeElement);            
            if (index > -1) {
                alert('indide');
                var nextElement = focussable[index + 1] || focussable[0];
                nextElement.focus();
            }
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    if (document.addEventListener !== undefined)
    {
            document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 9) {
                if (event.target.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
                    focusNextElement(event.keyCode);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        document.attachEvent('onkeydown', function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 9) {
                if (event.srcElement.tagName === 'INPUT') {
                    focusNextElement(event.keyCode);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You didn't describe what the problem is.  "It doesn't work" is not descriptive.

Comment: Polyfill here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill and here: https://gist.github.com/chrisjlee/8960575 - less than a minute to google

Comment: So either go look for polyfills that supply the needed functionality in IE 8 as well, or rewrite the code accordingly, so that it only uses methods available in IE 8 already ...

Comment: querySelectorAll should work in IE 8 already, if you are in standards mode - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16920451/1427878

Comment: The above code is not working when the page is rendering in IE8 (I should not emulate the page to IE11).  The javascript error is element is undefined. Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I need to get all the active elements in a page and need to perform some operations based on the returned values.

The below code is working when the page is rendering in IE11 but not in IE8. Could someone help me in fixing the code so that it should work in IE8 as well.

var focussableElements = 'select:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]),input[type=radio]:not([disabled]),input[type=text]:not([disabled]), [tabindex]:not([disabled]):not([tabindex="-1"])';

```
    if (document.activeElement && document.activeElement.form) {
        var focussable = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.activeElement.form.querySelectorAll(focussableElements),
function (element) {
    return element.offsetWidth > 0 || element.offsetHeight > 0 || element === document.activeElement 
});
        var index = focussable.indexOf(document.activeElement);
```